# Finding equilibrium point from a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the differential equation of a system as given below, $$ m\frac{d^2H}{dt^2} = mg-k\frac{I^2}{H^2} $$

How do I find the equilibrium points of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equilibrium points of the ordinary differential equation

$m \dfrac{d^2H}{dt^2} = mg -  k \dfrac{I^2}{H^2} \tag 1$

are characterized by the conditions

$ \dfrac{dH}{dt} = 0, \tag 2$

$ \dfrac{d^2H}{dt^2} = 0;\tag 3$

substituting (3) into (1) we find that the equilibria occur where

$ mg = k \dfrac{I^2}{H^2}, \tag 4$

that is, where

$H^2 = \dfrac{kI^2}{mg}; \tag 5$

thus, at equilibria

$H = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{kI^2}{mg}}. \tag 6$

***Note Added in Edit, Friday 10 September 2021 8:32 PM PST:***  Tbe reader might well be curious as to why, when the equilibria of (1) are characterized by conditions (2), (3), we only need find the values of $H$ corresponding to (3).  The answer may be found in the structure of the *phase plane* for the differential equation (1).  A second-order equation such as (1) may be thought of as a case of the general second-order system

$\ddot x = f(x, \dot x), \tag 7$

which in turn may be thought as a first-order system in two variables by taking

$y = \dot x, \tag 8$

so that

$\dot y =\ddot x, \tag 9$

and hence (7) takes the form

$\dot x = y, \tag{10}$

$\dot y = f(x, y), \tag{11}$

and the equilibria of this system ((10)-(11)) occur at those points $(x, y)$ where

$\dot x = \dot y = 0; \tag{12}$

(10) and (12) taken in concert yield

$y = \dot x = 0, \tag{13}$

and now (12) and (13) allow (11) to be written

$f(x, 0) = 0, \tag{14}$

which defines and constrains the relevant values of $x$, the ones corresponding to critical points of the system of ODEs (11)-(12).  We note that in accord with (4), all these critical points lie on the $x$-axis.

The developments expressed in this note are directly applicable to equation (1) above, which may indeed be written in the form

$\dfrac{d^2H}{dt^2} = g -  k \dfrac{I^2}{mH^2} \tag{15}$

***End of Note.***

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can solve such ODE by multiplying both sides by $\dot{H}$.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this topic as I haven't done anything related to it in the last 7-8 years. Can you explain further?

Comment: @MuhammedRoshan \begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{\mathrm dH}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2=2\frac{\mathrm dH}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm d^2H}{\mathrm dt^2}
\end{align} via the chain rule